# AWS Route 53 to redirect existing domain name to EC2 IP address

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, web-hosting

My website is running in AWS EC2, I want to redirect my dns name to public ip of ec2 server. How to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit httpd.conf file with following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domainname.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/awsec2
</VirtualHost>
```

Uncomment `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Restart Apache